# Como dar espaço entre os cards(alinhados) no materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

Alinhei os cards horizontalmente mas queria dar mais espaço entre eles para que não fiquem tão centralizados. Percebi que  faz com que eles fiquem centralizados, quando tirei os cards aumentaram de tamanho e ocuparam todo o espaço da DIV. gostaria de saber como mexer no tamanho dos cards. segue o código.

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col 12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/480x270/819602_c5df_2.jpg">
          <span class="card-title"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action center">
          <a href="#"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn yellow darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>Click Here</a></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/19/22/b0/1922b0418aa33e053e158158420a57a5.jpg">
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action center">
          <a href="#"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn yellow darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>Click Here</a></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-kuQIp1Ve4wE/VogACRfWWPI/AAAAAAAABDo/VA2VSsFN1Bw/s1600/Learn%2BJava%2BLike%2Ba%2BKid%2BBuild%2BFun%2BDesktop%2Band%2BMobile%2BApps%2B%2Budemy%2Bcupon%2Bcode%2Bfree.jpg ">
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action center">
          <a href="#"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn yellow darken-4"><i class="material-icons left">play_arrow</i>Click Here</a></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Olá Marcos, poste por favor um exemplo de código demonstrando um problema. Para mais informações de uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei mais informações. Espero que esteja mais claro. desculpem mas sou novo no desenvolvimento web. obrigado